# List Sheet ID's in column using Google Scripts

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get the sheet ID's to list in a column on the master sheet.

I have 15 sheets and I want to get the ID's of each to show on Master in column A1:A15.  I figured out from here how to get it into a popup window but cannot for the life of me get it to populate in cells.  When I try it only populates the last in the series in the cell instead of all of them.

```
function getSheetId()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
  var ids=[];
  for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++)
  {
    ids[allSheets[i].getName()]=allSheets[i].getSheetId();


  }
  var s='<table width="100%">';
  for(key in ids)
  {
    s+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td><strong>Sheet Name</strong></td><td>%s</td><td><strong>Sheet Id</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>',key,ids[key]);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D47').setValue(Utilities.formatString('%s %s',key,ids[key]));

    Logger.log(Utilities.formatString('%s %s',key,ids[key]));


  }
  s+='</table>'

  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(800).setHeight(450);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Sheet Keys for Spreadsheet: ' + ss.getName())


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

This put them into column 1:

```
function getSheetId()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
  var ids=[];
  for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++) {
    ids.push([allSheets[i].getSheetId()]);
  }
 sh.getRange(1,1,ids.length,1).setValues(ids);
}
```

This adds the dialog to the function:

```
function getSheetId1()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
  var ids=[];
  var html="<style>td,th{border: 1px solid black;}</style><table><tr><th>Sheet Name</th><th>ID</th></tr>";
  for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++) {
    ids.push([allSheets[i].getSheetId()]);
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',allSheets[i].getName(),allSheets[i].getSheetId());
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,ids.length,1).setValues(ids);
  html+='</table>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface,'Title');
}
```